# How to add master zone through PowerDNS API?

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

We have a PowerDNS master-slave setup. Now we want to use the PowerDNS API to automatically create master zones on the master server from our application. We created a master zone template, so when a domain is added the zonefile is automatically propagated with the correct records and notifies the slave.

I can't find any good reference on how to do this through the PowerDNS API. I want to post it a domain from the application and request it to make a new master zone file with the template.

Does anyone have a good example of an API call that can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you created your template in PowerAdmin web interface.

Unfortunately, you can't use templates from PowerAdmin in API call. PowerAdmin is just web based GUI with its own templates, but it's not part of PowerDNS itself. So you can't use that template in API call, because PowerDNS API doesn't know there's such a thing as PowerAdmin and its template.

However, you can create, for example, json template, that you can pass to PowerDNS API call.